# Change values of x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-visualization

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
input = np.arange(11,21,1)
sin = np.sin(input)
ax1.plot(sin)
plt.show()
```

I have the above code and it shows the plot with correct sin values for the given input from 11 to 20 but the x axis scale shows value from 0 to 10. I want it to be from 11 to 20. How do I do that or am I doing something wrong?

(Actually it works if I plot the graph from 0 to 21 and when I truncate the plot from 11 to 21.
With this:

```
np.arange(0, 21, 1)

ax1.set_xlim([11, 21])
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: You need `ax1.plot(input, sin)`. But you absolutely should choose a different variable name to avoid shadowing the built-in `input` function.

Comment: Thanku for replying! and yes I'll be careful about using keywords as variables

Answer (score 0):

`ax1.plot(input, sin)`

Also naming variable with `input` is a bad practice as it is a keyword

Comment: Thanku for the answer. And yes the input keyword, I'll remember it next time